# Не работает присвоение переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не присваивается 5 в конце

```
def func_outer():
    x = 2
    print('x равно', x)
    def func_inner():
        global x
        x = 5
    func_inner()
    print('Локальное x сменилось на ', x)
func_outer()
```

Comment: И не должно присваиваться, ведь вы сами указали интерпретатору, что хотите работать с глобальной переменной x в функции func_inner, а не с той x, которую использовали в функции func_outer как локальную.

Comment: Не надо так делать. Если в вашем коде вы используете global - то это на 99% означает, что вы делаете что-то не так. Значения, которые вы хотите посчитать в функции и передать за её пределы, следует возвращать через return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hужно заменить `global` на `nonlocal`:

```
def func_outer():
    x = 2
    print('x равно', x)
    def func_inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = 5
    func_inner()
    print('Локальное x сменилось на ', x)
func_outer()
```

Comment: подробнее прочитать можно тут https://python-scripts.com/scope

Comment: Второй print только надо сдвинуть вправо

Answer (score 3):

я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
def func_outer():
    x = 2
    print('x равно', x)

    def func_inner():
#        global x        # -
        x = 5
        return x         # +

    x = func_inner()     # + x = 
    print('Локальное x сменилось на ', x)

func_outer()
```